# Why is the 'mv' command not working when moving a file up multiple levels

Tags: linux, terminal, mv, sles

Operating system: SLES12 VM

So I start off in a directory:
**DirA**: `/home/user/testA/testB`

My goal is to move a file from this directory to a directory given by 
**DirB_rel**: `/home/user/testA/testB/../../deliverables/rpm/SOURCE`

Note: `testA` is a symlink which is not included in **DirB_abs**

Which, when I cd to it, gives a pwd of
**DirB_abs**:`/home/user/deliverables/rpm/SOURCE`

The problem is, when I try move a file using `mv` (have tried tar.gz and .txt) from DirA to DirB_rel, the file is deleted from original location as expected, but it does not appear at new location and is therefore lost.

E.g. `mv testFile.txt DirB_rel`  -> File disappears

However, when I use the absolute path for directory B, `mv` works correctly.

E.g. `mv testFile.txt DirB_abs`  -> Success

Any idea whats going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: protip: if you move a file to a directory, always use a trailing slash: `mv myfile mydir/` , such that if mydir does not exist, you get an error message instead of mydir being created *as a file* (the same if mydir does exist but *as a file* in which case the result will be even more disastreous)

Comment: do you have some symbolic links somewhere it the path?

Comment: @Nir Levy: Yes, testA (included in DirB_rel, the one I cannot move the file to) is a symlink. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the symlink. When you do `user/testA/testB/../../` and testA is asymlink, you wont go back to user, but to the parent directory of the directory testA links to

Comment: This was the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the mv command will reference the directory you are currently in and not from where the file is. So if we are in home ~/ and want to move ~/A/file to ~/B/file you use mv as follows:

```
mv A/file B/
```

Note that if you use this

```
mv A/file ../B/
```

the command will look for B in /home/B and not ~/B since we are in the ~/ directory issuing the command.

Comment: Hopefully this answers your question if not then if you could rephrase your question because it is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this though. The makefile I am using, is trying to `mv` a file to from current directory to DirB_abs but uses DirB_rel to achieve this. In my mind, they should be the same, although testA is a symlink.